# Connect Travis CI to SonarQube through a HAProxy with Basic Auth using Gradle

Tags: sonarqube, travis-ci, gradle-plugin

I'm trying to setup SonarQube for a Gradle project. I get it to play locally, but when using Travis CI I, run into problems. Travis cannot reach the SonarQube server through the HAProxy.

SonarQube server is behind a HAProxy with Basic Access Authentication. I have tried to use the name and password both as sonar.login/sonar.password and as auth credentials in the URL, but with no success.

```
sonarqubeSonarQube server [https://sonar.<domain>.com] can not be reached
```

or

```
sonarqubeSonarQube server [https://<name>:<password>@sonar.<domain>.com] can not be reached
```

Basically my build.gradle file contains this:

```
plugins {
    id "org.sonarqube" version "2.0.1"
} 
sonarqube {
    properties {
        properties["sonar.host.url"] = getProperty('SONAR_URL')
        properties["sonar.login"] = getProperty('SONAR_USERNAME')
        properties["sonar.password"] = getProperty('SONAR_PASSWORD')
    }
}
```

I had to remove the 'systemProp.' prefix to the properties in order to get it to work locally.

When running locally, I have a init.gradle file that contains this section, and it works nice.

```
allprojects {
    ext.set('SONAR_URL', 'http://localhost:9000')
    ext.set('SONAR_USERNAME', 'admin')
    ext.set('SONAR_PASSWORD', 'admin')
    ...
}
```

On Travis CI, I try to add environment variables for the job:

```
ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_SONAR_PASSWORD ••••••••••••••••
ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_SONAR_USERNAME ••••••••••••••••
ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_SONAR_URL      ••••••••••••••••
```

How can I get Travis CI to reach the sonar server that we have?

Comment: Did you try to reach your server with a simple curl? Just to see if the problem is on the SonarQube Scanner for Gradle or if it's more general.

Comment: Yes, with curl  on the format https://<name>:<password>@sonar.<domain>.com I can reach the server. When trying from Travis CI, it did not reach the Sonar server, and it printed an error messing in the Travis log with the name and pw in clear text... So currently I switched of the auth for sonar in the haproxy and relies on the build in authentication of sonar.

Comment: Was you able to resolve problem ? I have similar one, local build can upload successfully, but remote on Travis CI have the same problem as you have.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I ended up putting sonar server outside our ha-proxy relying only on the built in security of SonarQube